# Downloading a list of files with WGET - rename files up to .jpg ie. get rid of extraneous text

Tags: bash, grep, wget

My problem is pretty straightforward to understand.

I have `images.txt` which is a list of line separated URLs pointing to `.jpg` files separated as follows:

```
https://region.URL.com/files/2/2f/dir/2533x1946_IMG.jpg?Tag=2&Policy=BLAH__&Signature=BLAH7-BLAH-BLAH__&Key-Pair-Id=BLAH
```

I'm able to successfully download with `wget -i` but they are formatted like `2533x1946_IMG.jpg?BLAH_BLAH_BLAH_BLAH` when I need them named like this instead: `2533x1946_IMG.jpg`

Note that I've already tried the popular solutions to no avail (see below), so I'm thinking more along the lines of a solution that would involved `sed`, `grep` and `awk`

`wget --content-disposition-i images.txt`

`wget --trust-server-names -i images.txt`

`wget --metalink-over-http --trust-server-names --content-disposition -i images.txt`

`wget --trust-server-names --content-disposition -i images.txt`

and more iterations like this based on those three flags....

I'd ideally like to do it with one command, but even if it's a matter of downloading the files as-is and later doing a recursive command that renames them to the `2533x1946_IMG.jpg` format is acceptable too.

Answer (score 1):

#### 1) you can use `rename` in ONE liner to rename all files

```sh
rename -n 's/[?].*//' *_BLAH
```

- rename uses the next sintax `'s/selectedString/whatYouChange/'`
- `rename` uses **regex** to find all your files and also to rename using a loop. Because your name is very specific, you can select it very easy. you're going to select the char `?` and because in regex it has a special meaning youre going to put that in brackets `[ ]`. end result `[?]`.
- `-n` argument it's to show you what is going to change and not make the changes until you remove it. delete `-n` and changes will be applied.
- `.*` is for selecting everything after the char `?`, so `BLAH_BLAH_BLAH_BLAH`
- `//` is for remove what you select, because there are NOT words OR anything in here.
- `*_BLAH` is for selecting all files that end with _BLAH, you could use `*` but maybe you have other files, folders in that same place, so it's safer this way.
  *output*
  [image: rename blah files]

Answer (score -1):

```
find . \
  -name '*[?]*' \
  -exec bash -c $'for f; do mv -- "$f" "${f%%\'?\'*}"; done' _ {} +
```

- Why `*[?]*`? That prevents the `?` from being treated as a single-character wildcard, and instead ensures that it only matches itself.
- Why `$'...\'?\'...'`? The `$'...'` [ANSI-C-style string](https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/quoting#ansi_c_like_strings) quoting form allows backslash escapes to be able to specify literal `'` characters even inside a single-quoted string.
- Why `bash -c '...' _ {} +`? Unlike approaches that substitute the filenames that were found into code to be executed, this keeps those names out-of-band from the code, preventing [shell injection attacks](https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/Command_Injection) via hostile filenames. The `_` placeholder fills in `$0`, so subsequent arguments become `$1` and onword; and the `for` loop iterates over them (`for f; do` is the same as `for f in "$@"; do`).
- What does `${f%%'?'*}` do? This [paramater expansion](https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe) expands `$f` with the longest possible string matching the glob-style/fnmatch pattern `'?'*` removed from the end.

Comment: Works brilliantly - thanks! Would you mind explaining the different Regex used?

Comment: @LimeGiraffeGlacier, do the current edits explain everything appropriately? If not, could I ask you for a more specific description of what needs to be covered?